# Is this the right way to add restrictions to some class?

Tags: java, oop

*"Consider a class Register. It has two set of getters and setters. One for the professor and one for the student. Student can register itself but cannot get register data back. Professor, on the other hand, can register and view both its and students data. How this can be achieved in a mere public method."*

Below is my solution for the above question. Is the solution right if not why and what would be the right solution for this problem.

```
public class Register {
private String professor;
private String student;

public String getProfessor() {
    return professor;
}

public void setProfessor(String professor) {
    this.professor = professor;
}

public String getStudent() {
    return student;
}

public void setStudent(String student) {
    this.student = student;


   }
}
```

---

```
public class Student extends Register {

    public Student(String student) {
        super.setStudent(student);
    }

    @Override
    public String getProfessor() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getStudent() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setProfessor(String professor) {
        super.setProfessor(null);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Professor extends Register {

    public Professor(String student, String professor) {
        super.setStudent(student);
        super.setProfessor(professor);
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student std1 = new Student("Rumman");
        System.out.println("Data from Student Object");
        System.out.println("Student Name = " + std1.getStudent());
        System.out.println("Professor Name = " + std1.getProfessor());

        System.out.println("--------------------------");

        Professor prof1 = new Professor("Rumman", "Sadiq");
        System.out.println("Data from Professor Object");
        System.out.println("Student Name = " + prof1.getStudent());
        System.out.println("Professor Name = " + prof1.getProfessor());


    }
}
```

Output:

```
Data from Student Object
Student Name = null
Professor Name = null
--------------------------
Data from Professor Object
Student Name = Rumman
Professor Name = Sadiq
```

Comment: Put the `Professor` and the `Register` is in one package, put the `Student` in another. Use package level access control to restrict what methods are available. Just one possible option.

Comment: How about you run it and let us know?

Comment: `Student extends Register`?

Comment: Have you come across many students lately who were also registers?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch can you please elaborate your method.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem and +biziclop. This is just to check my solution. You can assume that class Student is named as RegisterStudent and class Professor as RegisterProfessor. Keeping this in mind what do you say about my solution.

Comment: The problem is you're using inheritance to simulate the "package private" access modifier.

Comment: @4castle okay. Can you guide me how Package private works and how to implement it and how can I use package level access control to restrict what methods are available. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create proxy that guards on real Register when student try to change some sensetive data:

Register interface

```
public interface Register {
    String getProfessor();

    void setProfessor(String professor);

    String getStudent();

    void setStudent(String student);
}
```

Real register

```
public class RegisterImpl implements Register {
    private String professor;
    private String student;

    @Override
    public String getProfessor() {
        return professor;
    }

    @Override
    public void setProfessor(String professor) {
        this.professor = professor;
    }

    @Override
    public String getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    @Override
    public void setStudent(String student) {
        this.student = student;


    }
}
```

And secure register

```
public class StudentRegister implements Register {
    private final Register register;

    public StudentRegister(Register register) {
        this.register = register;
    }

    @Override
    public String getProfessor() {
        throw new SecurityException("this is not allowed for students");
    }

    @Override
    public void setProfessor(String professor) {
        throw new SecurityException("this is not allowed for students");
    }

    @Override
    public String getStudent() {
        throw new SecurityException("this is not allowed for students");
    }

    @Override
    public void setStudent(String student) {
        register.setStudent(student);
    }
}
```

and Manager that's control register

```
public final class Manager {
    private final Register register;

    public Manager(Register register) {
        this.register = register;
    }

    public Register getRegister(String password) {
        if (password.equals("professor password")) {
            return register;
        } else {
            return new StudentRegister(register);
        }

    }
}
```

And test class

```
    public class Main {
        private final static Manager manager = new Manager(new RegisterImpl());

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            professorUser();
            studentUser();
        }

        public static void professorUser() {
            Register register = manager.getRegister("professor password");
            register.setProfessor("James Gosling");
            register.setStudent("Duke");
            System.out.println(register.getProfessor());
            System.out.println(register.getStudent());
        }

        public static void studentUser() {
            Register register = manager.getRegister("student password");
            register.setStudent("Duke"); // <- allowed
            // all actions below not allowed and cause exception when student try to do it
            register.setProfessor("None");
            register.getStudent();
            register.getProfessor();


         }
}
```